# Minion Pro bold and italic in mathmode

Tags: xetex, boldmath, minionpro

Does someone know how to write bold italic greek letters in mathmode with Minion Pro? The bm package doesn't seem to work

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[MnSymbol,quiet]{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathrm{Minion Pro} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[BoldFont={Helvetica Neue LT Std 65 Medium}]{Helvetica Neue LT Std}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}

\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

   \begin{equation}
     \bm{\beta}\beta
   \boldsymbol{\beta}\beta

\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: do you have the bold font?

Comment: yes, I have the bold font.